# Uploading Large database in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am using Apache, MySQL and phpMyAdmin.
So my sql file now is large and once I exported it I can't import it in another machine.
I am using iMAC and MacBook Pro.

I also tried to change the following in /etc/php.ini

- max_execution_time = 5000
- max_input_time = 5000
- memory_limit = 900M
- post_max_size = 750M
- upload_max_filesize = 750M

Then "sudo apachectl restart".

But It didn't work and I still cannot import my large database.
[image]

I also tried to upload my sql file in my terminal and it didn't work also.

Thank you

Comment: What happened when you tried it in the terminal?

Comment: "mysql server has gone away" is the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open mysql command prompt, and write following command, try thi

```
use database_name;
source path/of/sqlfile.sql
```

Comment: This indeed helped me in uploading my large sql file. Thank you very much.